# how to check second word is capital or not?

Tags: php

I want to check second word of string is in Capital or not. How can we check that in php.

Let say string is :

1. HELLO how are you.

now in that case i want to check HELLO is in Caps or not. How can we check that in PHP.

```
<?php

$regex = '/^[A-Z]*\s/m'; //Regular expression
$str = '1. HELLO how are you';

if(preg_match($regex, $str)) {
    echo 'First word is all capital';
} else {
    echo 'First word is not capital';   
}
```

I have tried below code but not working fine.

Comment: Would the input _always_ begin with a number followed by dot?

Comment: Non-regex solution: 1) Explode string on space; 2) Select second element and uppercase it; 3) Compare to original second element and see if they're identical.

Comment: Hii  Tim Biegeleisen yes the pattern is like this only.

Comment: As @El_Vanja said explode the string, then you can use ctype_upper() on the 2nd element

Comment: Can you explain (in the question) how it is "not working fine"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it...

```
$words = str_word_count($str, 1); //Grab all the words assuming words are just pure Alphabets

if(ctype_upper($words[0])){ //check if first word found contains all uppercase
echo 'First word is all capital';  
}  
 else {  
 echo 'First word is not capital'; 
 }
```